# OpenGL GLSL Shader not linking

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have a fairly basic shader  program but for some reason the shader program won't link. Code is below. The shader loader successfully loads the shaders but keep erroring when I attempt to link them with the program.

Shader Loader:

```
#include "Shaders.h"

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace myEngine
{
    bool Shaders::LoadShader(std::string _path, std::string _type)
    {
    std::fstream file(_path);
    char* shadersSrc = nullptr;

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.seekg(0, file.end);
        int length = (int)file.tellg();
        file.seekg(0, file.beg);

        shadersSrc = new char[length];

        file.read(shadersSrc, length);

        if (!file.eof())
        {
            file.close();
            std::cerr << "WARNING: COULD NOT READ SHADER" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }

        length = (int)file.gcount();

        shadersSrc[length] = 0;

        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "WARNING: COULD NOT OPEN SHADER" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (_type == "vertex")
    {
        m_vertexShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(m_vertexShaderId, 1, &shadersSrc, NULL);
        glCompileShader(m_vertexShaderId);
        if (!CheckShader(m_vertexShaderId)) return false;
    }
    else if (_type == "fragment")
    {
        m_fragmentShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(m_fragmentShaderId, 1, &shadersSrc, NULL);
        glCompileShader(m_fragmentShaderId);
        if (!CheckShader(m_fragmentShaderId)) return false;
    }

    return true;

}

bool Shaders::LinkShaders()
{
    m_programId = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(m_programId, m_vertexShaderId);
    glAttachShader(m_programId, m_fragmentShaderId);

    glBindAttribLocation(m_programId, 0, "in_position");

    glLinkProgram(m_programId);

    glGetProgramiv(m_programId, GL_LINK_STATUS, &m_success);

    if (!m_success)
    {
        std::cerr << "WARNING: COULD NOT LINK PROGRAM" << std::endl;
        //throw std::exception();
        return false;
    }

    glDetachShader(m_programId, m_vertexShaderId);
    glDeleteShader(m_vertexShaderId);
    glDetachShader(m_programId, m_fragmentShaderId);
    glDeleteShader(m_fragmentShaderId);

    return true;
}

bool Shaders::CheckShader(GLuint _id)
{
    glGetShaderiv(_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &m_success);
    if (!m_success)
    {
        std::cerr << "WARNING: COULD NOT COMPILE SHADER" << std::endl;
        throw std::exception();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

The Fragment Shader is:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

The Vertex Shader is:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 in_position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(in_position, 1.0);
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated as is for a university module.

Edit: the program doesn't throw any errors. It just says it can't link program which is on line 76.

Edit: this has now been resolved. It was just a typo on my part.

Comment: Doesn't give any errors. Only stops at the exception throw

Comment: You need to read the program linker log using [`glGetProgramInfoLog`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgramInfoLog.xhtml).

Comment: Thanks, used this and it has come up saying 0(5) : error C1013: function "main" is already defined at 0(5). Any ideas?

Comment: copy/paste issue: `m_fragmentShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);` -> `m_fragmentShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);`

Comment: This has solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I made a typo on line 52. should have been `GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER` instead of `GL_VERTEX_SHADER`.